# Make Application_BeginRequest handle all request including static files

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis, iis-7

How can I make Application_BeginRequest handle every single request including static files?

Global.ascx.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{

}
```

I currently have this on my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I am using II7 and my app pool has integrated as the managed pipeline mode.

In it's current state it fires the event for .aspx pages but not for files such as images.